# How to inject mathjs into Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, mathjs

How can I inject mathjs into Angular.js?

I can't get it to work - I used `bower install mathjs --save` to install it.

Update: The JS min file is properly injected into index.html

Do I need to inject it into the main module or into the controller? I tried both and got a white screen on page load with an error message about the non-availability of the module.

Comment: You do not need to inject in any module because angular will not treat it as dependency.. check http://mathjs.org/   can you tell me how are u loading math.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Step 1

```
bower install mathjs --save
```

### Step 2

Reference mathjs in your main html page

```
<script src="path/to/bower_components/mathjs/dist/math.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### Step 3

This dependency is not *angular-aware*, there is no module to inject as a dependency of your angular application. As mathjs exposes a global `math` object, you can use it in an angular component as follows :

```
math.round(0.123, 2) // gives back 0.12
```

Comment: Nah, my GruntFile already took care of injection into index.html. How can I access this now in a controller?

Comment: mathjs exposes a global `math` object, so you should be able to play with it in your components.

Answer (score 5):

As time passed, I'm adding this updated response.

If you're using *Angular*, chances are that you're using `npm` as well. To add *mathjs*, you can follow the [official procedure](https://mathjs.org/download.html)

```
npm install mathjs
npm install @types/mathjs
```

The two above commands will update the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` as needed.

Then, as described in the [Getting Started](https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html), you need to import separately each of the *mathjs* commands you want to use. So, for example, to perform square root in a *typescript* class:

```
import { sqrt } from 'mathjs';


export class MyClass {
    function calculate(n: number): number {
        return sqrt(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it really works!